# What will happen to the additional CSS when the theme is updated?

Tags: customization, css, theme-customizer

I have a premium theme installed and I need to add some custom CSS to add some new styles.

So what will happen if I add the CSS to the additional css section in the customize? Will I lose them when the theme is updated?

Should I install a plugin or create a simple one for this?

I tried to search about that, But didn't find an answer.

Comment: Normally the css will be saved in the database I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing. The Additional CSS section of the customiser will be unaffected by updating the theme.

The reason you may have seen warnings regarding updating themes and losing customisations is because when themes are updated, all of its files are replaced with fresh copies. So the reason you lose changes is because if you modified the themes files then they have been overwritten with copies that don’t have your changes. None of this is relevant to the Customiser, because it doesn’t modify theme files.

Comment: Which is exactly the point of the Additional CSS section. Without it, if you wanted to keep your changes to the CSS, however minimal, you would need to create a child theme.